# Node.js' http.Server and http.createServer, what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the difference between:

> http.Server(function(req,res) {});

and

> http.createServer(function(req, res) {});

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on the source code of nodejs (extract below), `createServer` is just a helper method to instantiate a `Server`.

Extract from [line 1674 of http.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L1674).

```
exports.Server = Server;


exports.createServer = function(requestListener) {
  return new Server(requestListener);
};
```

So therefore the only *true* difference in the two code snippets you've mentioned in your original question, is that you're not using the `new` keyword.

---

For clarity the `Server` constructor is as follows (at time of post - 2012-12-13):

```
function Server(requestListener) {
  if (!(this instanceof Server)) return new Server(requestListener);
  net.Server.call(this, { allowHalfOpen: true });

  if (requestListener) {
    this.addListener('request', requestListener);
  }

  // Similar option to this. Too lazy to write my own docs.
  // http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/half_closed_clients/
  // http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InnerWorkings#What_is_a_half-closed_filedescriptor.3F
  this.httpAllowHalfOpen = false;

  this.addListener('connection', connectionListener);

  this.addListener('clientError', function(err, conn) {
    conn.destroy(err);
  });
}
util.inherits(Server, net.Server);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much. In the interest of readability, could you add the `Server` constructor to your code example?

Comment: @wulfgar.pro No problem, added now

Comment: So that means, with `createServer`, we can make multiple servers.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener), it seems to be

```
http.createServer = function (requestListener) {
     var ser = new http.Server();
     ser.addListener(requestListener);
     return ser;
};
```

Comment: Could you point where this is stated? You link is the whole page, any link to the paragraph you are referring to?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Updated. I was referring to "*Returns a new instance of `http.Server.` The `requestListener` is a function which is automatically added to the `'request'` event.*" (or whatever the text was years ago - it looks like `addListener` doesn't exist any more)

Comment: Thanks, actually it points to the source code which is even simpler: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2817fde844de39b0e8c17c352433ee6124b5ef09/lib/http.js#L39

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev I'm pretty sure it wasn't that simple in 2012, the signature of `Server` changed

Comment: Oh, haven't realized your answer is that old. But since it links to the current Node.js version, maybe update the code to reflect it?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev I'll rather link the old version of the docs - the text was indeed the same